# Image Comparison in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a web application, Computerized Voting System using ASP.NET. i want to compare thumb impression from database. I'm using disconnected data access. is it possible to compare an input thumb impression with a thumb print already saved in SQL database? if yes then then how?

Comment: BTW, did you know there's nothing called "ASP.NET C#"? ASP.NET and C# are two separate things, sometimes used together.

Comment: No i didn't knew that. I'm a newbie. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please describe some details of the application.

The images that are saved in the database, are they uploaded with the same application ? If so, you should add a new column where you will store the hash of the image.

You will have a table like this: |ID|ImageData|Hash|

This is how you can compute the hash:

```
string hash;
using(SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(byteArray));
}
```

Then, when you want to check if an uploaded image already exists in the database, you should compute the hash for it and send a query like:

```
string.Format("SELECT ID FROM Images WHERE Hash={0}", hash);
```

This will tell you if the exact same bytes are already in the database. If the image is similar, it will not work. It must be identical.

NOTE: you will have to convert your image into a byte array. This should not be a problem if you already do this when saving images in the database.

You might want to look in Computer Vision and Principal Component Analysis if you want to look for similarities between images.